# ML.NET: Can we re-train Matrix Factorization Model using learned model parameters

Tags: c#, ml.net

In ML.NET, I'm try to retrain an existing matrix factorization model for a recommendation system using c#. Howver, I'm not able to find an resources on how this could be done. Even the official microsoft page doesn't have any info on re-training matrix factorization algorithm. Seems like they only support re-training of selected algorithms. Is there anyway this could be done as I have to re-train the whole model every time I have new data that needs to be utilized. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Link of microsoft page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net

I'm still in the learning stages and it would be really helpful if there is a way in which I can re-train the existing matrix factorization model as this would save a lot of time.